# How to paginate a class-based list view with django-filters

Tags: django, pagination, django-filter, django-pagination, django-filters

Do you guys know how to paginate a generic class-based ListView that uses django-filters as a search bar? When I read some articles regarding this issue(which wasn't a lot for class-based views), it seems that django-filters and pagination don't work together very well. Here is my view:

```
class StudentListView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "leads/student_list.html"
    context_object_name = "leads"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = StudentFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        organisation = self.request.user.userprofile
        return Lead.objects.filter(organisation=organisation).order_by('first_name')
```

I would really appreciate it if you guys could tell me what code I need to write for my view as well as what code I need to add into my template to make pagination work. I don't think the code for the actual filter and the template is necessary, but if you guys need it, I can add it to this question. Thanks.

For additional information, I am going to add the following pagination code to my template:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
  <div class="pagination">
      <span class="page-links">
          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
              <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
          {% endif %}
          <span class="page-current">
              Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
          </span>
          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
              <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
          {% endif %}
      </span>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`FilterView`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#generic-view-configuration) that is provided by django-filter. Also this class inherits from `MultipleObjectMixin` so it is capable of performing pagination, so if you set `paginate_by` attribute on the class it will perform pagination too:

```py
from django_filters.views import FilterView


class StudentListView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    template_name = "leads/student_list.html"
    context_object_name = "leads"
    filterset_class = StudentFilter
    paginate_by = 10 # Change as per your preference
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        organisation = self.request.user.userprofile
        return Lead.objects.filter(organisation=organisation).order_by('first_name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The search bar works fine, though. The issue I don't know how to solve is how to paginate this list.

Comment: @JohnSong `FilterView` inherits from `MultipleObjectMixin` so it can perform pagination for you. I have edited the answer to show how to do that

Comment: So, I am going to add the code added to the question above into my templates. I initially wrote {% for lead in filter.qs %} in my forloop as well. How should I change filter.qs to make this work?

Comment: `{% for lead in object_list %}` or as per your `context_object_name` use `{% for lead in leads %}` (Also the context would have a variable `filter` as well, also all variables you expect like `page_obj` etc. would be available)